# How to access CDI beans in JSP pages

Tags: jsp, cdi

I want to set up CDI in my existing JSF 2-Websphere application.I am using CDI Conversional scope for state saving.

I have included bean.xml in WEB-INF and annotations in my class.But still I couldnt access CDI bean inside JSP pages.can anyone provide any samples on how this be done?

Comment: Is it neccessary to add any folder inside META-INF.

Answer (score 1):

The [Weld home page mentions](http://seamframework.org/Weld) as

> For Servlet Containers (Tomcat/Jetty) or Java EE 5 Application Servers:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The [18.3. Servlet containers (such as Tomcat or Jetty)](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.5.Final/en-US/html/environments.html#d0e5223) also told us as

> While JSR-299 does not require support for servlet environments, Weld can be used in a servlet container, such as Tomcat 6.0 or Jetty 6.1.
>
> Weld can be used as a library in an web application that is deployed to a Servlet container. You should place `weld-servlet.jar` within the `WEB-INF/lib` directory relative to the web root. `weld-servlet.jar` is an **"uber-jar"**, meaning it bundles all the bits of Weld and CDI required for running in a Servlet container, for your convenience. Alternatively, you can use its component jars. A list of transitive dependencies can be found in the `META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt` file inside the `weld-servlet.jar` artifact.

Firstly we also need to explicitly specify the servlet listener (used to boot Weld, and control its interaction with requests) in `WEB-INF/web.xml` in the web root:

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I hope this may help.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But i want websphere default implementation of CDI.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine in WebSphere 8.5.5. You need to annotate class with `@Named("yourName")` and usually with some scope related annotation.
Then you can access your bean in plain jsp using EL like this: `${yourName.property}`

Answer (score 1):

Following is an example to used an CDI @Named annotated class in JSP

class :

```
@RequestScoped
@Named(value = "emp")
public class Employee {

    int empno;
    String ename;
    double salary;

    public Employee() {
        this.ename="Shankar";
    }

    public int getEmpno() {
        return empno;
    }

    public void setEmpno(int empno) {
        this.empno = empno;
    }

    public String getEname() {
        return ename;
    }

    public void setEname(String ename) {
        this.ename = ename;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }


}
```

Now the JSP Fragment to use this class

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <NoAutoGeneratedIdViewHandlertitle>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Hello World!</h1>

        ${emp.ename}
    </body>
 </html>
```

This @Named annotated classes can be used in EL in JSP

Hope this satisfies you. Pl. ask for any clarification