# CDI in JSP ( not JSF ) on Tomcat 10 ( jakarta.servlet.* )

Tags: jsp, cdi

**Spec :** TOMCAT10 , weld -libraries from jboss

**Process :** Trying (CDI) insert from input-text to pojo from a pure simple JSP Page

```
<form method="get">
  <table  width="25%" border=1>
   <tr>
   <td>Name :</td>
   <td><input type="text" maxlength="10" id="login" name="login" value="${bean.input}"/></td>
   </tr>    
   <tr>
   <td colspan=2>
   <button type="button" id="TEST" value="${bean.submit()}"   name="TEST" />TEST-CDI</button>   
   </td>
   </tr>  
   </table> 
   </form>
```

Pojo is as follows

```
@Named()
@RequestScoped
public class Bean implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String input;
    private String output;

    //Get/setters
    public String getInput() {return input;}
    public void setInput(String input) {this.input = input;}
    public String getOutput() {return output;}
    public void setOutput(String output) {this.output = output;}
    public void submit() {
        output = "Hello World! You have typed: " + input;
        System.out.println("SUBMITTED : " + output);
    }
}
```

**O/p :** SUBMITTED : Hello World! You have typed: null

Question :  Why Injection of InputText not passed to pojo ?

**Leads :** No post avaliable on WWW (google/yahoo....)

with regards
karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Why Injection of InputText not passed to pojo ?*

Because this is not done by CDI.

You basically forgot to create a servlet like below:

```java
@WebServlet("/yourServlet")
public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    private Bean bean;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        bean.setInput(request.getParameter("login"));

        if ("submit".equals(request.getParameter("action")) {
            bean.submit();
        }

        request.getRequestDispatcher("your.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

You only need to adjust form and submit button as follows:

```html
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/yourServlet" method="post">
    ...
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="submit">TEST-CDI</button>
    ...
</form>
```

CDI basically only autocreates bean instance when referenced for the first time in a particular scope, such as `${bean}` in EL or `@Inject` in some container managed component such as a servlet or another bean. CDI doesn't at all collect and set submitted HTTP request parameters. That's the responsibility of a servlet.

Do note that when using JSF, the entire `YourServlet` is unnecessary and you only need a view (like that JSP page) and a model (like that CDI bean). That's the whole point of JSF. It comes with its own `FacesServlet` which does this all automagically. And it does even more, such as (implicit) conversion, validation and, importantingly, XSS attack prevention.

#### See also:

- [Easy way of populating Javabeans based on request parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096454/easy-way-of-populating-javabeans-based-on-request-parameters/)
- [Prepopulate AND redisplay an HTML Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879806/prepopulate-and-redisplay-an-html-form/)
- [Design Patterns web based applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications)
- [What is the need of JSF, when UI can be achieved with JavaScript libraries such as jQuery and AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421839/what-is-the-need-of-jsf-when-ui-can-be-achieved-with-javascript-libraries-such)

Comment: Hi This URL "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895343/how-to-access-cdi-beans-in-jsp-page"s   has  CDI  from POJO to JSP GET values,  So my question why not from  JSP to POJO  POST Values ...Is this impossible  with out servlet ?  

Note: - This is similar to using JSF where POST/GET of CDI works

Comment: That's already answered above.